# Indesign Javascript to copy link names to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am trying to create an Adobe Indesign JavaScript that will copy the link names of the selected items to the system clipboard. Example if I had 3 frames selected with 3 different images placed into them on the clipboard I would get

**Image01.jpg**

**Image02.png**

**Image03.pdf**

```
try {
  // Get the selected items
  var selectedItems = app.activeDocument.selection;

  // Initialize an empty array to store the file names
  var fileNames = [];

  // Check if there are any selected items
  if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
    // Loop through the selected items
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
      // Check if the selected item is an Link
      if (selectedItems[i] instanceof Link) {
        // If it's an image, add the file name to the array
        fileNames.push(selectedItems[i].itemLink.name);
      }
    }

    // Check if the file names array is empty
    if (fileNames.length > 0) {
      // Join the file names into a single string
      var fileNamesString = fileNames.join("\n");

      // Copy the string to the clipboard
      app.copy(fileNamesString);
    }
    else {
      // If the file names array is empty, display an alert message
      alert("None of the selected items are images.");
    }
  }
  else {
    // If there are no selected items, display an alert message
    alert("Please select at least one item.");
  }
}
catch (e) {
  // If an exception is thrown, display an alert message
  alert("An error occurred:\n" + e);
}
```

So far I have tried running the code above but it is not working and throws an error both if I have a frame selected with a link in it and if I have nothing selected.

**An error occurred:
TypeError: undefined is not an object**

Help getting this to work much appreciated.

Comment: The selection object will show things that have been selected on the page. If you've selected an image on the page the class of that selection is likely to be "image" (depending on how it was selected, it may also be some type of frame, often a "rectangle"). If the class is an image, that image will have an "item link" and that "item link" will have a "name". If the class is "rectangle" it will have "all graphics" that contains "image".

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line:

```
if (selectedItems[i] instanceof Link) {
    // If it's an image, add the file name to the array
    fileNames.push(selectedItems[i].itemLink.name);
}
```

with

```
try { fileNames.push(selectedItems[i].graphics[0].itemLink.name) }
catch(e) { fileNames.push(selectedItems[i].itemLink.name) }
```

And this obvious approach `app.copy(fileNamesString);` doesn't work in InDesign. Unfortunately.

If you want to put text into the clipboard you have to create a text frame, put the text into the frame, select the text and then use `app.copy()` method.

Here is the dedicated function:

```
function copy_to_clipboard(text) {
    var frame = app.activeDocument.pages[0].textFrames.add();
    frame.geometricBounds = [0,0,200,100];
    frame.contents = text;
    frame.parentStory.texts.everyItem().select();
    app.copy();
    $.sleep(300); // just in case
    frame.remove();
}
```

And now you have replace the line:

```
app.copy(fileNamesString);
```

with

```
copy_to_clipboard(fileNamesString);
```